# Find The Samples In VST Instruments

Tags: vst, instrument, samples

Many sample players like Kontakt have special files (nkx) that house the samples in which it uses within a DAW.

Anyone know how to get to the actual wav files? I've heard this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for kontakt you do this...

open kontakt load a file/instrument you want...go to "mapping editor" double click any sample that is mapped on the keyboard, "wave editor" should open, then move your mouse on sample name and it should show you a path, where that sample is.

like this.. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/sampleqt.jpg/

Comment: Thanks for this! Ill check it out. Trying to wrangle in all the audio I have for indexing

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to open kontakt stand alone, and collect samples /  batch compress the patches you have in mind.  This way you can choose un compressed wav. and itll save them to a sample directory of your choosing.  Although this may be something blocked with official native instrument libraries with protected samples :(

most people only use compressed native instruments files as its a severe drop in file size.

Cam